# HTTP post with angular on a "before auth" laravel route

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, angular-http

I authenticate my user only through laravel, so angular does not know about it. But I need to do a $http.post on a "before auth" route with angular in order to get some profil info:

### laravel route.php

```
Route::post('profile', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}));
```

### angular app.js

```
$http.post("/profile").success(function (data) {
    $scope.profile = data;
  });
```

For now I get an internal server error (500) with a "Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException" because laravel think I'm not logged in.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Could be helpful](http://dmlogic.com/blog/securing-angular-with-laravel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, it was a csrf filter that was causing this error, not the auth filter...

For reference to my question:

> AJAX Requests are identical with regular requests in regards to session data. Anything that depends on Session or Auth will work with an AJAX call.

[link to thread](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5436)